# Confirmation Popup when poppingViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableViewController that loads up a TabBarViewController on selecting a row.

The user can change information on the screen, and then hit the `Back` button in the Navigation controller. The TabBarViewController is of kind Show (e.g. Push) via a storyboard segue.

If the user changes something on the screen and then hits the back button, I want to be able to display an alert asking if they really want to leave this screen. OR if they switch tabs.

I used [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028677/how-to-create-a-confirmation-pop-up-when-pushing-back-button-in-ios) as a reference however I can't seem to get it to hook up right.

If you look at below screenshot you can see my tabs are broken up into various items.

[image]

The "Vehicle View Controller" is where I would like to monitor for changes using a bool `didMakeChanges` that gets set to true when edits are made.

In my `viewDidLoad` in the VehicleViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    didMakeChanges = false;

    //Here I am holding a reference to the TabViewContoller
    self.mvc = (MasterTabViewController*)self.tabBarController;


    UIBarButtonItem *bbtnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"GO" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: bbtnBack];

}

- (void)goBack:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (didMakeChanges) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Changes Made"
                                                        message:@"Discard the vehicle changes without saving?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch(buttonIndex) {
        case 0: //"No" pressed
            break;
        case 1: //"Yes" pressed
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment what fails? Does it not push the tab bar, does the alert view not appear when you click back? Also does each one of your tabs have a navigation bar?

Comment: The alertview does not fire. I have included the delegate. All tabs share the same Nav controller. The tab VC is embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: Okay, a break point triggers if you set one in the goBack method, obvious I know, but worth checking. Have you tried using UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView?