# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method toString when using switch-case inside it

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to visualize the `toString()` value of my object during debug, I receive this message.
My `toString` method is this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String s = "ACTION: <P"+this.playerSit+" "+this.type;
    switch(this.type){
    case DISCARD:
        s+=" "+this.cardDiscarded+">";
        break;
    case CALLVALUE:
        s += " "+this.valueCalled+">";
        break;
    case CALLSCORE:
        s += " "+this.scoreToWin+">";
        break;
    case CALLSUIT:
        s += " "+this.suitCalled+">";
        break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

before adding the switch-case construct it worked fine.

EDIT: I modified the code as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String s = "";

    s += "ACTION: <P"+this.playerSit+" "+this.type;

    if(this.type == Type.DISCARD)
        s += " "+this.cardDiscarded+">";
    if(this.type == Type.CALLVALUE)
        s += " "+this.valueCalled+">";
    if(this.type == Type.CALLSCORE)
        s += " "+this.scoreToWin+">";
    if(this.type == Type.CALLSUIT)
        s += " "+this.suitCalled+">";
    return s;
}
```

and now it works again. So the problem is the switch-case, but I don't know why.

Comment: What's the error? What is the datatype of this.type?

Comment: Unrelated-but-related: Don't create strings using `+=`: Use a `StringBuilder` instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.type` is `null`.  Add an if check for null before your switch statement to verify.

Comment: excuse me but if this.type was null it should simply return "ACTION: <P0 null" in both cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can't switch on null.  It raises a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `InvocationException` is really masking a `NullPointerException`, which can occur when you do not have a `default` case in your switch statement. See [this previous stack overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649423/should-switch-statements-always-contain-a-default-clause) (especially number 2 of the most popular answer) for why including a `default` case is useful and the [Oracle documentation on switch statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for some string examples with `default` cases.