# Why should each case in a switch statement that isn't the default cover an exceptional condition?

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

My book on Java seems to suggest that [in switch statements each case that isn't the default should cover an exceptional condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5c6w.png) What is the meaning of this and why is it recommended? Can you provide any examples to illustrate the point?

Edit: 
I think I got the meaning/implication of the original quote: Inputs or situations that don't meet your initial expectations almost always need to be covered, and the default case in switch statements supplies a way to do so.

Comment: Maybe what the author meant was that if there's only one condition per switch-case, you should use an if-else structure, but I can't be sure.

Comment: No way to answer without context.

Comment: Added an image with the quote.

Comment: This give an explanation of what the author meant by that http://stackoverflow.com/a/5241196/1925997

Comment: That's not even what it says. It says to provide a default handler so you are forced to handle conditions that don't match any of the case statements--*that* is the "exceptional condition"--conditions that don't match the cases you provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should switch statements always contain a default clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649423/should-switch-statements-always-contain-a-default-clause)

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't say it said so. It was suggested or implied.

Comment: No it isn't-what you said is basically backwards. The cases you provide are explicitly *not* exceptional, because you expected them, and coded for them. "Exceptional" means rare or unanticipated.

Comment: It is somewhat counter-intuitive that the _default_ case handles _exceptional_ conditions, since "default" and "exceptional" are essentially opposites.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit to your second comment, @DaveNewton.

Comment: Might indeed have been what tripped me up, @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what the author wrote. He said:

> Including a default case focuses you on the need to process exceptional conditions.

What he meant is, you are going to add everything you are thing to the switch case, and then adding a default will guarantee that you will think about every other possibility. For instance, if you switched for animals, "cat", "dog", "pig", well, what if the user input something else? Adding a default forces you to think about that, and handle errors and exceptional cases appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps I did misunderstand it after all. My original thoughts were that it meant exceptional conditions should be covered in all cases, and anything regular in the default.

Comment: No, that's pretty much the opposite: handle regular cases, and add a default case to force yourself to think about all other (exceptional) cases -- those are very easy to forget, when you have something in your head, like "it's going to be 'Y' or 'N'", handling other cases you don't want to see scarcely crosses the mind.

Comment: BTW: not having a deault when you switch on an enum can be helpfull, as it allows you to recognize if a new enum was added but no handling code for it.