# How to use a named routes in a BottomNavigationBar in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, navigationbar

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` and when clicked on any icons in the navigation bar. I want it to go to next screen. That's why I am using named route here.

`main.dart` code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Screens/profilePage1/profilePage1.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyStatefulWidget());

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;



  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
            routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/first': (context) => ProfilePage1(),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/second': (context) => ProfilePage1(),
        '/third': (context) => ProfilePage1(),
        '/fourth': (context) => ProfilePage1(),
        '/fifth': (context) => ProfilePage1(),
      },
      home: Scaffold(
        
        body: Center(
          child: routes.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text("")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  size: 35,
                  color: Color(0xFF334192),
                ),
                title: Text("")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text("")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.table_chart), title: Text("")),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF334192),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          onTap: (index){

          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have created 5 named routes. And I want it to pass to body when particular tab is clicked. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **Navigator.pushNamed()**

```dart
onTap: (index){
  switch(index){
      case 0:
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/first");
        break;
      case 1:
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/second");
        break;
        ...etc
    }
 },
```

Navigator.pushedName() needs **context** to find the **Ancestor** Widgets which contains the Navigator routing, now your BottomNavigationBar is already in the Root Widget-**MaterialApp**, which **is not** the Ancestor of the BottomNavigationBar, they are in the same context.

Comment: why is it giving this error? Can you help me with this?
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
descendant of a Navigator widget.

Comment: @AmanChaudhary Extract your Scaffold Widget to a Stateless/Stateful Widget may solve the error

Comment: this did solve the problem but what was the reason behind this?

Comment: @Aman Chaudhary This because your 'MyStatefulWidget' class doesn't have a MaterialApp as a parent. You can take a look for more explanation from Rémi Rousselet here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51292613/7610338

Comment: Is also good practice with a switch to have a default: that goes to home screen/page or an error screen/page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649423/should-switch-statements-always-contain-a-default-clause

Answer (score 4):

Just use pushNamed method of Navigator
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Name');
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html

```
 onTap: (index){
   switch (index) {
     case 0:
       Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/first');
     break;
     case 2:
       Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
     break;
 },
```